# complex grid layout for legacy devices

Tags: css, layout

I am trying to achieve the following layout:

[image]

With the following html:

```css
.large {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 60px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 60px);
  grid-gap: .25em;
  margin: 1em;
}

.large div {
  background: lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.delete {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2
}

.ok {
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 3 / span 2
}

.zero {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2
}
```

```html
<div class="large">
  <div (click)="tap('<')" class="delete">X<i class="theme-delete-i"></i></div>
  <div (click)="tap('1')" class="one">1</div>
  <div (click)="tap('2')" class="two">2</div>
  <div (click)="tap('3')" class="three">3</div>
  <div (click)="tap('4')" class="four">4</div>
  <div (click)="tap('5')" class="five">5</div>
  <div (click)="tap('6')" class="six">6</div>
  <div (click)="tap('7')" class="seven">7</div>
  <div (click)="tap('8')" class="eight">8</div>
  <div (click)="tap('9')" class="nine">9</div>
  <div (click)="tap('0')" class="zero">0</div>
  <div (click)="tap('.')" class="separator">.</div>
  <div (click)="ok()" class="ok "><span>OK</span></div>
</div>
```

and it works fine! But the problem is i have to support old browsers and old devices like iphone 5 and 6 where display: grid-like  is not supported yet. i am looking for help with achieving this layout with display: table or display: table-cell or something else which is compatible with old android/ios devices.

Comment: Have try with `<table>`?

Comment: Nope because on the top div  there is a class "large". This keyboard view has 3 different layouts and other two are with different look. the idea is with one html to keep 3 different looks